# How can I set custom meta tags with the pdflib library?

Tags: php, pdflib

I am using pdflib library to generate pdf in php. I am able to create the pdf with this library but yet not able to generate custom meta tags for pdf.

can any one help me out from this, so that I'm able to generate meta tags for my pdf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use PDFlib PLOP can be found on

http://www.pdflib.com/products/plop/

With the help of this you can set your meta tags for your pdf.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like thats what I'm looking for

Comment: try for that and let me know if you have any difficulties in that.

Answer (score 2):

Standard document information tags are `Subject, Title, Creator, Author, Keywords, Trapped`.

You use them this way (at least in pdflib 7):

```
PDF_set_parameter($p, "hypertextencoding", "unicode");
PDF_set_parameter($p, "hypertextformat", "utf8");
PDF_set_parameter($p, "usehypertextencoding", "false");
PDF_set_parameter($p, "textformat", "utf8");
PDF_set_info($p, "Creator", $Creator);
PDF_set_info($p, "Author", $Author);
PDF_set_info($p, "Title", $Title);
PDF_set_info($p, "Subject", $Subject);
PDF_set_info($p, "Keywords", $Keywords);
```

And to define userdefined tags, use:

```
PDF_set_info($p, "MyCustoMKey", $MyCustomValue);
```

User defined tags cannot be: `CreationDate, Producer, ModDate, GTS_PDFXVersion, GTS_PDFXConformance, ISO_PDFEVersion`.

This is enough to get custom tags into pdf. But if you literally want them as xmp, you can autopopulate your custom info to xmp using option `autoxmp=true` when calling `PDF_begin_document()`:

```
if (PDF_begin_document($p, $pdf_output_file, "autoxmp=true") == 0) {
  die("Error: " . PDF_get_errmsg($p));
}
```

I have tested the above in real code and can confirm that it works.

Alternative (and a little more complex) way is [this](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/document-interchange/embed-xmp/php-embed-xmp/).

This example uses utf8, which is preferable nowadays due to globalisation. So convert your php-file to use utf8 as mime-encoding using your file editor (UltraEdit, Textmate etc.) or by using command line tool [iconv](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding).

Comment: Wait, is there really no way to override `Producer`? It's a commercial library, that developers need to **buy** for commercial use and **still** have no option to hide the fact they use it, by customizing, or better yet, _removing_ the Producer tag altogether? What a pathetic excuse of a PDF library.